# How to get pandas series Value counts with a series in original index order after value preference

Tags: python, pandas

Below I present Example:

```
a = ['Ibrutinib', 'Ibrutinib', 'Ibrutinib',
       'Ibrutinib-containing product', 'Ibrutinib 140 MG',
       'Ibrutinib Oral Product',
       'Ibrutinib-containing product in oral dose form', 'Ibrutinib Pill',
       'Ibrutinib Oral Capsule', 'Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule',
       'Ibrutinib 140 MG [Imbruvica]',
       'Ibrutinib Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]',
       'Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]']

pd.Series(a).value_counts()

%%out%%
Ibrutinib                                         3
Ibrutinib-containing product in oral dose form    1
Ibrutinib Pill                                    1
Ibrutinib Oral Product                            1
Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]         1
Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule                     1
Ibrutinib Oral Capsule                            1
Ibrutinib-containing product                      1
Ibrutinib 140 MG [Imbruvica]                      1
Ibrutinib 140 MG                                  1
Ibrutinib Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]                1
dtype: int64
```

I would like to see the "Ibrutinib 140 MG" in 3 position as it comes ahead in the original series.

Answer (score 1):

To sort by the original list, convert it to a dataframe, then create a rank column to sort by.

```
import pandas as pd

a = ['Ibrutinib', 'Ibrutinib', 'Ibrutinib',
       'Ibrutinib-containing product', 'Ibrutinib 140 MG',
       'Ibrutinib Oral Product',
       'Ibrutinib-containing product in oral dose form', 'Ibrutinib Pill',
       'Ibrutinib Oral Capsule', 'Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule',
       'Ibrutinib 140 MG [Imbruvica]',
       'Ibrutinib Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]',
       'Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]']


s = pd.Series(a).value_counts()
df = s.rename_axis('value').reset_index(name='count')   # convert to dataframe
df["rank"] = df['value'].apply(lambda x : a.index(x))   # create rank column, ranked by list index 
dfsrt = df.sort_values(by='rank')                       # sort by rank
print(dfsrt[['value','count']].to_string(index=False, justify='left',  # display value and count
     formatters={'value':'{{:<{}s}}'.format(dfsrt['value'].str.len().max()).format}))
```

Output

```
 value                                           count
 Ibrutinib                                       3
 Ibrutinib-containing product                    1
 Ibrutinib 140 MG                                1
 Ibrutinib Oral Product                          1
 Ibrutinib-containing product in oral dose form  1
 Ibrutinib Pill                                  1
 Ibrutinib Oral Capsule                          1
 Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule                   1
 Ibrutinib 140 MG [Imbruvica]                    1
 Ibrutinib Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]              1
 Ibrutinib 140 MG Oral Capsule [Imbruvica]       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = pd.Dataframe(a)
df = df.groupby(0, sort=False).size()\
    .sort_values('size', ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
```

Value_counts sorts by default quicksort which is not guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: Its because when we group the axis length change. ```list(df.columns)``` makes no change in error

Comment: I got a desired result by not using the excess code ``` sort_values('size', ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
```

Comment: ```pd.DataFrame(a).groupby(0, sort = False).size()```

Comment: Great, keep in mind that sort might be needed with a larger dataset

Comment: I understand one thing is. It works only for this data provided but doesn't solve the problem

Comment: the error is being received because of the column name you are giving a 'size'. But there is no column size as it is a pandas series with 0 named.

Comment: yeah found it finally. Merge sort disturbs the index when it is a pandas series but not a dataframe.